# How can i inject angular router in script tag in index.html?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Is there a way to get the router object from index html script tag?
Not found any info on web.
Tried some old answer with coreTokens but seems its jot valid on ivy.
Thanks

Comment: Injecting Angular Router directly into a <script> tag in the index.html file is not a typical approach in Angular development. Angular Router is a core part of the Angular framework and is typically set up and managed within the context of Angular components and modules.

If you want to use Angular Router, you should follow the standard Angular practices for setting up routing. https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Do you need the Router (service)? Or the actual defined routes?

Answer (score -1):

An angular router object is typically not accessible directly from the index.html file's script tag because the router is part of the Angular framework and is managed within Angular components and modules. The index.html file is usually the entry point for the Angular application, and it serves as a container for the Angular components rendered by the application.

If you want to interact with the Angular router, you typically do so from within your Angular components using Angular's built-in mechanisms. Here's how you would work with the router within an Angular component:

In your component's TypeScript file, you import the Angular Router module like this:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

You can inject the Router object into your component's constructor using Angular's dependency injection system:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    // Now you can use 'this.router' to work with the router
}
```

With the Router object available in your component, you can use its methods and properties to navigate and manipulate routes within your application. For example:

```
this.router.navigate(['/new-route']);

const currentRoute = this.router.url;
```

Comment: I need to access the router from the script. If i have the ng object so i cant use the injector to get the router?